# Why the Jpa N+1 is something so bad?

Tags: sql, jpa

I know that we must avoid that behavior,  using join fetch instead of letting the JPA manage it by making multiple queries, but the question is: **why it's so bad performatic since we calling all queries in the same session?**

Exemplo :

1. ```
   Select * from person 
   Select * from accounts
   ```
2. ```
   Select * from person p left join fetch p.accounts
   ```

My question is just about performance, what the justification for the last one be more performatic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because there's more than just retrieving the data when you run a query. The other phases can be quite expensive. To name a few:

1. Prepare the connection.
2. The query is sent through the wire to the database server.
3. The db engine parses the query. The cache is populated.
4. The db engine rewrites/rephrase the query to suit internal needs.
5. The cache is checked. Otherwise is populated and managed.
6. The db engine evaluates multiple execution plans for the query.
7. The db engine chooses the *optimal* execution plan somehow.
8. The **query is run**, the data is retrieved, and this has I/O consequences.
9. The result set is returned throught the wire.

You may have considered the query only included the **query is run** phase, while in reality there are many other tasks the db is performing.

Also, once a single I/O operation retrieves many rows at once, and you would be discarding many of those unnecessarily.

Comment: I undestand your points, and im grateful..but, since we are working in the same session working with JPA , i dont think that we need to prepare a connection, and to worry about most of the phases that you describem

Comment: @BrunoSerqueira If you are using "connection pooling" (you probably are because of JPA) you don't need to consider step #1. However, you are still affected by all other steps.